# How should I start undergraduate research in Artificial Intelligence?

Tags: research-process, undergraduate

I am currently an undergraduate student, pursuing my Integrated Masters of Technology in Mathematics and Computing from Indian Institute of Technology, Dhanbad. I would like to do original research and publish a paper on Artificial Intelligence by the end of my course. Unfortunately, none of the professors in department are willing to help in my chosen topic and some have recommended that change it. I would like to know if it will be feasible for me working in AI research mostly on my own, and some pointers on how I should proceed?
I would also like to know what research topics related to computer science I should explore?

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to understand the basics of AI. If you are taking an undergraduate course on artificial intelligence, you should first think about finishing the course by making sure that you understand well these basic concepts about AI. You may want to read a few books on this topic.

Second, if you want to do research, you will need to know what researchers are currently doing. So you will need to read research papers about AI to see what is the current state-of-the-art research on a sub-topic of AI, because what is written in the textbook or what you learn in your course may not be the state-of-the-art. This will give you some ideas about what you can improve. Then, you can work on improving it and publishing your results.

I highly recommend that you work under a supervisor. The goal of a master degree is to introduce you to research and the goal of a Ph.D. is that you become a researcher, and there are reasons why this process takes several years, and is done with a supervisor. If you do research on your own, there are many mistakes that you can do that a supervisor could tell you not to do.

Lastly, I don't think that it is realistic to write a research paper before the end of your course on AI.  Don't forget that what you learn in your undergraduate course is probably from a textbook and it may not be the state-of-the-art research. Besides, producing a first paper may typically take a few months full time for a master degree student, so you would likely not have enough time.